# How to calculate the HMAC(hsa256) of a text using a public certificate (.pem) as key

Tags: python, jwt, hmac

I'm working on Json Web Tokens and wanted to reproduce it using python, but I'm struggling on how to calculate the HMAC_SHA256 of the texts using a public certificate (pem file) as a key.
Does anyone know how I can accomplish that!?

Tks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you use so far. Where does it fail? How?

Answer (score 2):

In case any one found this question. The answer provided by the host works, but the idea is wrong. You don't use any RSA keys with HMAC method. The RSA key pair (public and private) are used for asymmetric algorithm while HMAC is symmetric algorithm.

In HMAC, the two sides of the communication keep the same secret text(bytes) as the key. It can be a `public_cert.pem` as long as you keep it secretly. But a `public.pem` is usually shared publicly, which makes it unsafe.

Comment: Yes the Idea is wrong and insecure. I would say no security at all. But that is the whole point of the PTL exercise to show this :)

Comment: The key used in HMAC is symmetric  by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got this after 22 hours of study/google.

---

**Spoiler Alert**

Since this is one of pentesterlab's pro exercises, I'll not post the code demonstrating how to generate a full JWT using HSA256. 
Instead, it'd be better if I post how to do calculate the HSA256 using a pem file in python, as it was my original question:

```
import hashlib
import hmac

key = open("public_cert.pem","r").read()
signature = hmac.new(key, unsignedToken, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
print signature
```

Basically we just need to read the public key file and use the hmac.new(..) function, setting hashlib.sha256 as the digest to be used.
The "unsignedToken" is the JWT text (or declarations) that we wanted to calculate the signature.

For those still trying to figure it out how to create a valid JWT for pentesterlab's exercise, the only hint I can give is to urlsafe-base64 encode everything.
There is also a python module, named "pyjwt" that can be used, but its source code must be edited to allow public keys to be used as a HMAC key.

Comment: I would like to add that the code above does not work in python 3. It needs to be: `signature = hmac.new(key.encode(), unsignedToken, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()` also a tip for the PentesterLab exercise: download and save the public key pem file and not copy paste it. :-)